# Magento 1.9.3 Place Order not working

Tags: magento-1.9, place-order

Am using `Magento 1.9.3` with **coolbaby** theme. I have a problem in `Place Order`.

When i click `Place Order` button showing some `error` in `console` those error is in  following image 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Did you check the url that is coming on button? Seems you might have changed the default action on the button

Answer (score 1):

1) Check the code bellow in : `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/onepage/link.phtml`

```
<?php if ($this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()):?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Proceed to Checkout')) ?>" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> no-checkout<?php endif; ?>"<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif?>
```

2) Check if you have installed some extension who rewrite the `templates/checkout/onepage/review.phtml`, try to uninstall the lastest extentions.

Comment: Thanks for your code Prince. You are right in `link.phtml` page i have write some customized code. But same code working in Live server. In local i got this error https://ibb.co/cwD3M5

Comment: In `checkout/onepage/` when i move to `ORDER REVIEW` showing some errors in console

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using third party modules . Kindly disable your local modules then check.

you can disable your all local module from here:

```
app/etc/local.xml
```

go to line no 36.change "false " to "true"

```
<disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>
```

Now clear cache and check

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Coolbaby has **HTML/CSS** Bugs on mobile display.
When the button doesn't work in narrow width display, observe the mouse-over action.

I had added br-tags to below phtml, and **"Place Order"** button started to work with Smartphone.

```
template/checkout/onepage/review/button.phtml
```

```
template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have fixed this issues already